# SharePoint 2007 WSP Deployment Best Practices

Tags: sharepoint, iis, deployment, wsp

I'm building a few WSPs (a custom web part and a branding wsp both scoped to site collection level) using WSP builder on VS2010.  Our SharePoint 2007 Farm contains two Web applications.

I'd like to know whether deployment of a WSP to a particular web application (Web App A) will only recycle the application pool for that given web application (Web App A). And that the other web application (Web App B) would be unaffected during this process.

What I want to ensure is users of the other web application won't experience any down time in anyway during this release and that the wsp appears only in one Web App when viewing the site collection features lists.

Does this type of deployment only cause app pool recycling or does IIS get reset too?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSP deployment only recycles the app pool containing your site collection, as opposed to an iisreset which resets all app pools.

Users of the other web application will experience down time during this deployment only if the two web applications share the same app pool (unlikely in best practice SharePoint setup).

The WSP will appear only in one site collection features list, the site collection where it was deployed.

WSP Builder is a good tool to use in VS2010 for SharePoint 2007 deployment, the tool is correct in terms of paths and naming and can be trusted!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm also trying to make a provisioning feature (masterpage, page layouts etc) become targeted to a web application but it keeps globally deploying any ideas around this?

Comment: Please upvote useful answers and mark one of the answers as the best answer to your question. People will then invest time to help you.

Comment: Post your WSP somewhere and I will have a look at why it is globally deploying as you mentioned it is site-col-scoped.

Comment: The feature is scoped at Site (site collection level).  But when deploying the wsp via STSADM it doesn't give the option to deploy to a specific web application on instead it deploys globally to all web applications.  I think this may be to do with WSP builder and that it always builds wsps with a manifest.xsl which deploys assemblies to the GAC rather then the BIN directory for a given web application.  Also noticing that using WSP builder to add Feature Receivers causes issues when trying to deactivate a feature not sure if the assemblies for feature receivers always need GAC deployment?

Comment: When deploying via STSADM you specify a URL, this URL should discriminate between the different web applications. The way you deploy has nothing to do with WSP Builder's generated manifest file. What errors are you getting on deactivating feature?

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2010 and wspbuilder 2010 will possibly give you an incorrect structure or naming. Just thinking about the 14 hive and the 12 hive. I might be wrong but worth a check.

However back to your question.

Adding a solution(WSP) to the farm should have any impact on what the users see.

Deploying the solution causes the Application pool of the given web application to recycle. Remember that(i have seen this) some places host many on one application pool meaning you will effectively see anything attached to that application pool suddenly become slow/ unresponsive for a short period of time.

Theoretically as long as Web App A and Web app B are on seperate application pools you should only see one or the other affected ( depending where your deploying)

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/385eb454-5083-47a6-b378-615b67a065a3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm also trying to make a provisioning feature (masterpage, page layouts etc) become targeted to a web application but it keeps globally deploying any ideas around this?

Comment: When you say deploying globally., What do you mean? The wsp package as far as im aware deploys your features to the provided web app Are you deploying via powershell?, These are deployed to a location (Site collection features etc) based on the scope you set within the feature.XML in visual studio

Comment: The feature is scoped at Site (site collection level).  But when deploying the wsp via STSADM it doesn't give the option to deploy to a specific web application instead it deploys globally to all web applications.  I think this may be to do with WSP builder and that it always builds wsps with a manifest.xsl which deploys assemblies to the GAC rather then the BIN directory for a given web application.  Also noticing that using WSP builder to add Feature Receivers causes issues when trying to deactivate a feature not sure if the assemblies for feature receivers always need GAC deployment?

Comment: Stsadm commands normally ask for a -URL property, This should place the features in the right location but for some reason i remember setting my features to web i think to get the features to only display in the site i targetted in the -URL of the stsadm scrip. DOn't hold me to this but play around with a new project with a blank feature! I think they do do always need to be in the gac, I've never known my assemblies to go anywhere else

Comment: Please remember you are moving away from the main quetion asked. You need to mark something as answered(if it's answered your original q) and start a Q if you have Q's about stsadm.